# Pycharm change color unresolved reference

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm color coding question.

Using pycharm, i always miss the "unresolved reference" indicator - it is light gray. I am assuming that, like all the other items in pycharm i can change its color etc. What/where is the option to change the color for this item?

Extra sentence because the above question wasn't worthy. actually, make that two extra sentences, and some lingo:

```
if i > 5:
    i = 4 || 5
    i = 6
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check **Warning** and **Weak warning** colors in `Editor | Colors & Fonts`:

[image]